# What do require 'bundler/setup' and 'Bundler.require' do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

In Rails application, in `boot.rb`, there is a line:

```
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```

In `application.rb`, there is another line:

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

Could you briefly explain what Rails / Bundler do at `require 'bundler/setup'` and at `'Bundler.require'`?

Is it valid statement, that Bundler is required at `bundler/setup` and all gems from `Gemfile` are required at `Bundler.require`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `require 'bundler/setup'` does is make Rails automatically discover the Gemfile and then add all the gems defined in it to Ruby's load path.

`Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)` will then require all the gems in the Gemfile depending on the current Rails environment. So if current environment is the development environment, Rails will load all gems that are meant to be used in the development environment.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful!